# Checking out Android source from github

Tags: android, git, repository, android-source

After going through all of these steps to check out the Android source code (Gingerbread branch), only to come to a compile error, I have decided to try to get the source code from a different source.

Here are the steps that I have taken to checkout the source code from the GitHub.com repository.

I checked out the repo tool from the GitHub.com repository

```
git clone git://github.com/android/tools_repo.git
```

Inside the repo script file that was downloaded, I changed the location of the repo tool as follows:

```
## repo default configuration
##
#REPO_URL='git://android.git.kernel.org/tools/repo.git'
REPO_URL='git://github.com/android/tools_repo.git'
REPO_REV='stable'
```

After this, I created the repository for the source code using the repo script 'git wrapper'.

```
repo init -u git://github.com/android/platform_manifest.git -b gingerbread
```

Which gave me a successful results; "repo initialized in /home/my/directory"

However, when I try to `repo sync`, I get the following error message:

```
$ repo sync

Initializing project platform/bionic ...
android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
error: Cannot fetch platform/bionic
```

Where are the references to the now-offline android.git.kernel.org?  `cat repo|grep kernel.org` gives me nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://plus.google.com/100301252568537087423/posts/3NngLGAjVgG) you can find the howto on checking out from github.

Comment: Link seems to be offline as google+ is not available anymore

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [default manifest](https://github.com/android/platform_manifest/blob/dc01e28756c1f28197de70f74a6f2ca108d78b74/default.xml) in the platform_manifest repository, you'll see that kernel.org is still used quite frequently.

You'll have to wait for kernel.org to come back online, or consider hacking on CyanogenMod, which has a working manifest.

EDIT: It appears that all of the Korg repos are mirrored on GitHub. In that case, try patching with [this pull request](https://github.com/android/platform_manifest/pull/1) and then try a repo sync.

Comment: See this is what I was afraid of.. waiting.  How does codeaurora.org allow me to check out the whole branch? Sure it doesn't compile, but it should be possible using a find/replace?

Comment: I've updated my answer, try patching using that pull request and you should be syncing with GitHub rather than Korg.