# Checkout Android source using repo from github

Tags: android, github, repository

The question is the same as [Checking out Android source from github](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7761518/567555); however the answers no longer apply. The links to the gist in the blog post pointed out by the first answer there is no longer available. Can someone indicate how this may be done, if at all possible, for recent versions of Android (>= 4.1)?

Answer (score 0):

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

You will want to follow this. They changed the method of which you get the source unfortunately.

Comment: yes, I know this. My question was how to configure repo tool to download from github.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the grave dig, but I've just gone through a very similar situation.

The trick is to use ssh:// prefix instead of git://, as your usually using keys to access github. 
Your url might end up being something like this:

```
ssh://git@github.com/project_namespace/myawesomeproject.git
```

This obviously relies on your system having ssh keys setup previously.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not get how to configure repo to get everything from github.

Comment: I would suggest reading over [this](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt)